# Tkinter's overrideredirect() behaving oddly (Python 3.2, Win7)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my application to use `Toplevel` windows without frames, but when I try to use `overrideredirect` right after creating the Toplevel, it isn't displayed at all. If I call `overrideredirect` separately, for example by pressing a button that calls it for the last created `Toplevel`, it works as expected. 
Is this behavior somehow intended, or at least sensible? How can I work around it?

Comment: Can you give us an example program that exhibits this behavior? What you say is happening is not intended behavior, and I don't recall anyone noticing this before.

Comment: Isn't your `Toplevel` simply under another window created by your program ? What happens if you raise it ? For instance, check http://pastebin.com/A5D7RpWa for an example.

Comment: I am having the same problem, as soon as I added the overriderredirect(True) to my code, the window no longer shows up. If I remove it, it works as expected, but I want to get rid of the titlebar.

Comment: Some more info. I am trying to make a modal window with no title bar. When I remove the lines "self.toplevel.transient(root)" and "self.toplevel.grab_set()", overrideredirect starts working, but I lose my modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Found a link which fixed he issue for me.

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html

> Be sure to call the .update_idletasks() method (see Section 26,
>   “Universal widget methods”) before setting this flag. If you call it
>   before entering the main loop, your window will be disabled before it
>   ever appears.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on macOS 10.12.5 with Python 3.6.1 and tcl/tk 8.5.18 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802456/tkinter-splash-screen-multiprocessing-outside-of-mainloop/44851222#44851222)). As suggested in comments above, calling `.lift()` on the toplevel window right after `.overrideredirect(True)` is called fixed the problem for me.