# Can python installation on Mac be forced to use tcl/tk 8.6?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'd like to know how to get the official python installation from python.org (3.6.1) for Mac to use tcl/tk 8.6. I have been using different releases of tcl/tk 8.5 with tkinter for my project's GUI and I keep running into very limiting bugs (crash on scrolling, [window-mgmt issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802456/tkinter-splash-screen-multiprocessing-outside-of-mainloop) among others).

Since I did not encounter the same problems on Windows using 8.6, I suspect/hope that using the newer tcl/tk could make things easier on mac, if it is possible to properly combine it with python/tkinter.

IDLE is not important for me (in case it will not work with tk 8.6.). I also know of similar older questions on SO, which usually resulted in references to the [official python.org page](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) about this issue (stating to use 8.5) and I'm also aware of this [python bug tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue15663).

I'd still like to know whether using tcl/tk 8.6 on mac is possible, how it can be achieved and what potential drawbacks would be.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom part of `python.org/download/mac/tcltk` explains that macOS will only link a binary compiled for tcl/tk 8.5 with some version of 8.5.  I believe that there are sources for python macOS binaries other than python.org that are compiled for tcl/tk 8.6.  Try Homebrew?, MacPorts? other?? (I don't have a mac and have only read the names, but no reviews.)

The 3.7.0 PSF Mac installer will supposedly be switched to using tk 8.6.  The current 3.7.0a2 has not be switched, yet, and I don't know when the change will be made.  I hope by 3.7.0b1 in late January.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'll maybe try to mess around with homebrew/macports binaries, once I find time. Re. 3.7.0 PSF installer: is there any official information available concerning the switch to tcl/tk 8.6?

Comment: I don't believe so.